# Android Camera Preview color differs from jpeg from Camera.takePicture

Tags: android, image, camera, jpeg, preview

I have an application built which is displaying a camera feed. The user is able to take a picture by pressing a button.

The color of the preview seems to be different than the picture of the jpeg that results from taking the picture on at least one device (MotoG). I don't see this behavior when testing on an LG-P700.

Any idea why this would be?

Below are attached images for what I'm seeing. Notice how the Preview is more yellow than the other images. (The device camera has a little yellow too, but not as much as the preview.)

PREVIEW
[image]
JPEG
[image]
DEVICE CAMERA
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can be a brightness issue. When the camera starts the brightness is max by default and when it closes, it comes back to the one set by user.

Comment: I'm not changing the brightness of the camera at all.

Comment: Have you tried setting the brightness to max while checking the jpeg from the sdcard? Try that. See if it changes anything.

Comment: @Tushar do you mean the general screen brightness or something in code?

Comment: Gotcha. I'll see what that turns up.

Comment: No luck. It still has the same yellowish tint added, regardless of what the screen brightness is.

Comment: Give me the apk, I'll check that on my Moto G.